# How to disable Spell Checker in eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I recently installed HTML plugins in my Eclipse Luna. From that I am getting Spell check with "Sp" as showed below. How do I remove this from Eclipse?

[image]

Comment: somewhere like this: Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Spelling->Enable Spell Checking

Comment: i already tried that, But it is not working. this is not default eclipse plugin, this came from web tools platform

Comment: Check your Annotations preference page to see what is actually set to show that "Sp." I'd be surprised if it was actually spelling errors.

Comment: I checked it , it is sowing as spelling mistake

Answer (score 15):

Follow this path.
Preferences -> JDT Spelling -> Uncheck 'Enable Java name spell checking'

Comment: "Preferences > Java > JDT Spelling >  Enable Java name spell checking"  on my Mars version, but yeah, worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

just try this:
Window->Preferences :: General->Editor->Text Editors->Spelling Now, uncheck the box "Enable spell checking or the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-ByTpPV1sI)

Answer (score 0):

Go into Window>Preferences
Search "spelling"
Uncheck "Enable spell checking"

[image]